# FluentNHibernate HasMany not filling child collection

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, informix

I am working with tables Factura and DetalleFactura, the problem is when I get one Factura not filling  collection of DetalleFactura.

clsFacturaModel and clsDetalleFacturaModel have a composite id.

I include additional information about other classes because they are part of composite ids.

Models:

```
public class clsCiaModel
{
    public virtual string Cve_cia { get; set; }
    public virtual string Nom_cia { get; set; }
    public virtual clsDireccion Direccion { get; set; }
    public virtual string Rfc_cia { get; set; }
}

public class clsPlantaModel
{
    public virtual clsCiaModel Cia_pla { get; set; }
    public virtual string Cve_pla { get; set; }
    public virtual string Nom_pla { get; set; }
    public virtual clsDireccion Direccion { get; set; } 
    public virtual string Tel1_pla { get; set; }
    public virtual long Fnvta_pla { get; set; }
}

public abstract class clsaBase
{
    public virtual clsPlantaModel Planta { get; set; }
}

public class clsFacturaModel : clsaBase
{      
    public virtual string Tfac_fac { get; set; }      
    public virtual int Fol_fac { get; set; }
    public virtual string Ser_fac { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? Fec_fac { get; set; }
    public virtual clsClienteModel Numcte_fac { get; set; }
    public virtual string Tpa_fac { get; set; }
    public virtual string Edo_fac { get; set; }
    public virtual string Impr_fac { get; set; }
    public virtual clsCfdModel Cfd { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<clsDetalleFacturaModel> Detalle { get; set; }
}

public class clsDetalleFacturaModel : clsaBase
{    
    public virtual clsFacturaModel Fol_dfac { get; set; }
    public virtual short Mov_dfac { get; set; }
    public virtual string Tid_dfac { get; set; }
    public virtual int? Fnvta_dfac { get; set; }
    public virtual int? Ffis_dfac { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal? Tlts_dfac { get; set; }
    public virtual string Tpr_dfac { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal? Pru_dfac { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal? Ivap_dfac { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal? Simp_dfac { get; set; }
}
```

Map:

```
public clsCiaMap()
{
    Table("cia");     
    Id(c => c.Cve_cia, "cve_cia");
    Map(c => c.Nom_cia, "nom_cia").Length(40);
    Map(c => c.Rfc_cia, "rfc_cia").Length(15).Nullable();
    Component(c => c.Direccion,
     d =>
     {
         d.Map(dir => dir.Dir, "dir_cia").Length(40).Nullable();
         d.Map(dir => dir.Col, "col_cia").Length(40).Nullable();
         d.Map(dir => dir.Ciu, "ciu_cia").Length(40).Nullable();
     });
}

public class clsPlantaMap : ClassMap<clsPlantaModel>
{
    public clsPlantaMap()
    {
        Table("planta");
        CompositeId()
            .KeyProperty(p => p.Cve_pla, "cve_pla")
            .KeyReference(p => p.Cia_pla, "cia_pla");
        Map(p => p.Nom_pla, "nom_pla").Length(40).Nullable();
        Map(p => p.Tel1_pla, "tel1_pla").Length(30).Nullable();
        Map(p => p.Fnvta_pla, "fnvta_pla");
        Component(c => c.Direccion,
        d =>
        {
            d.Map(dir => dir.Dir, "dir_pla").Length(40).Nullable();
            d.Map(dir => dir.Col, "col_pla").Length(40).Nullable();
            d.Map(dir => dir.Ciu, "ciu_pla").Length(30).Nullable();
        });
   }
}

public class clsFacturaMap : ClassMap<clsFacturaModel>
{
    public clsFacturaMap()
    {
        Table("factura");
        CompositeId()
            .KeyProperty(f => f.Fol_fac, "fol_fac")
            .KeyProperty(f => f.Ser_fac, "ser_fac")
            .KeyReference(f => f.Planta, "pla_fac", "cia_fac");
        Map(f => f.Edo_fac, "edo_fac").Length(1).Nullable();
        Map(f => f.Fec_fac, "fec_fac").Nullable();
        Map(f => f.Impr_fac, "impr_fac").Nullable();
        References<clsClienteModel>(f => f.Numcte_fac, "numcte_fac").Nullable().Not.LazyLoad();
        Map(f => f.Tfac_fac, "tfac_fac").Length(1);
        HasMany<clsDetalleFacturaModel>(f => f.Detalle)
            .KeyColumns.Add("fol_dfac", "ser_dfac", "pla_dfac", "cia_dfac")
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
            .Inverse()
            .AsBag()
            .Not.LazyLoad();//COLLECTION EMPTY
    }
}

public class clsDetalleFacturaMap : ClassMap<clsDetalleFacturaModel>
{
    public clsDetalleFacturaMap()
    {
        Table("det_fac");
        CompositeId()
                .KeyProperty(df => df.Mov_dfac, "mov_dfac")
                .KeyReference(df => df.Fol_dfac, "fol_dfac", "ser_dfac", "pla_dfac", "cia_dfac");
        Map(df => df.Ffis_dfac, "ffis_dfac").Nullable();
        Map(df => df.Fnvta_dfac, "fnvta_dfac").Nullable();
        Map(df => df.Ivap_dfac, "ivap_dfac").Nullable();
        Map(df => df.Pru_dfac, "pru_dfac").Nullable();            
        Map(df => df.Simp_dfac, "simp_dfac").Nullable();
        Map(df => df.Tid_dfac, "tid_dfac").Length(1).Nullable();
        Map(df => df.Tlts_dfac, "tlts_dfac").Nullable();
        Map(df => df.Tpr_dfac, "tpr_dfac").Length(3).Nullable();
    }
}
```

I dont get any error, but collection(Detalle) is always empty